# React new Set method how can access the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, set

I am using react, how can i access the these two values ? Anyone help ?

```
var names = messages.map(function(item){
     return item.sender.title
    
    })
    let uniqueChars = [...new Set(names)];
```

[result of console.log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOmmB.png)

```
console.log(uniqueChars[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with the map function.

```
uniqueChars.map(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```